# lubridate `period` versus `as.numeric`

Tags: r, lubridate

Is there any reason why I should prefer `/dseconds()` over `as.numeric`? It seems the latter is a little bit faster. They both give the same results.

```
> as.numeric(lubridate::ymd_hms("2015-12-31 23:59:59 UTC") - lubridate::ymd_hms("2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"), units = "secs")
[1] 31535999
> interval(lubridate::ymd_hms("2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"), lubridate::ymd_hms("2015-12-31 23:59:59 UTC"))/dseconds(1)
[1] 31535999
```

and the microbenchmark test:

```
summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  as.numeric(lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-12-31 23:59:59 UTC") - lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"), units = "secs"),
  interval(lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"), lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-12-31 23:59:59 UTC"))/dseconds(1),
  times = 100L, unit = "ms"))
```

giving

```
                min       lq     mean   median       uq      max    neval
as.numeric   3.095075 3.161979 3.320435 3.225082 3.293127 5.634390   100
/dseconds(1) 3.940120 4.067465 4.209389 4.163069 4.259054 6.072688   100
```

I guess there is some further reason for the extra functionality `interval/dseconds()`

Comment: Indeed, in your case, I guess you can tick to `as.numeric`. `interval` is really nice in cases you need to compute less standard differences (in quarter for example)

Comment: @Eric Lecoutre: From the `difftime` docs `as.numeric` can handle `"secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"`. `periods` are `dweeks, ddays, dminutes, dseconds`. So it's quite the same? It even seems, `as.numeric` has more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically no big difference concerning the results. See also the comment in @Stibu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881270/switch-between-dates-and-seconds-in-a-well-defined-manner).