# Switch between dates and seconds in a well defined manner

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I run discrete event simulations where the time originates from dates. I think that simulations run much faster, when I convert all the dates to integers (relative time in `seconds`).
What is the best way, to switch between `date` and `seconds` in a well definied way where I want to

- set the reference time (e.g. `"1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"` or `"2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"`) manually,
- the time zone and
- the origin (Not possible in `lubridate`?)

I thought I can use the `origin` for this purpose but it does not influence the result:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT",origin="2016-01-01",tz="GMT"))
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT",origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT"))
```

both result in `[1] 1451606400`.

(Only the `tz` argument changes the result, which is ok of course:
`> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00 CEST", tz= "America/Chicago"))`
`[1] 1451628000`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `difftime()` to calculate the difference between some timestamp and a reference time:

```
as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00",tz="GMT"),
    as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00",tz="GMT"), units = "secs"))
## [1] 1451606400
```

By choosing another value for `units`, you could also get the number of minutes, hours, etc.

The reason that you get the same result for both choices of `origin` is that this argument is only intended to be used when converting a number into a date. Then, the number is interpreted as seconds since the origin that you pass to the function.

Internally, a POSIXct object is always stored as seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, UTC, independent of the origin that you specified when doing the conversion. And accordingly, converting to numeric gives the same result for any choice of origin.

You can have a look at the documentation of `as.POSIXct()`:

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.POSIXlt(x, tz = "", format, ...)

## S3 method for class 'numeric'
as.POSIXlt(x, tz = "", origin, ...)
```

As you can see, `origin` is only an argument for the method for `numeric`, but not for `character`.

Comment: You would prefer that over lubridate functionality like `interval(lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"), lubridate::ymd_hms("1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"))/dseconds(1)`? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted after writing the first lines of my answer. I now added an explanation why you got the same result independent of `origin`.

Comment: Regarding `lubridate`: I can't think of anything that is wrong with what you propose. I'm using lubridate a lot, but I knew `difftime()` (which is base R) before I had heard of lubridate. So it just stuck.

Comment: Ok. So you also answerd [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878693/lubridate-period-versus-as-numeric): There is basically no difference?

Comment: Well, the two approaches are different, since they use different functions and have intermediate results with different classes. So they are definitely not doing exactly the same thing under the hood. But they lead to the same result.